# How is a minibatch processed by the GPU in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to understand how PyTorch actually performs a forward pass over a minibatch. When a minibatch is processed by a network, is each example in the minibatch (e.g. each image) sent forwards individually, one after the other? Or are all examples in the minibatch sent forwards at the same time?

When an example is sent forwards through a network, the additional memory requirement is the activations at each layer. And as long as the network does not take up the entire GPU, then it seems that multiple instantiations of these activations could be stored at the same time. Each instantiation could then be used to store the activations for one example in the minibatch. And therefore, multiple examples could be sent through the network simultaneously. However, I'm unsure whether this is actually done in practice.

I have done some simple experiments, and the time for a forward pass is roughly proportional to the minibatch size. This suggests that the examples are sent through one after the other. If so, then why is it that people say that training is faster when the minibatch size is larger? It seems that the processing time for an entire epoch would not be dependent on the minibatch size.

Comment: Please also post your simple experiment's code and results in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to understand how PyTorch actually performs a forward pass over a minibatch. When a minibatch is processed by a network, is each example in the minibatch (e.g. each image) sent forwards individually, one after the other? Or are all examples in the minibatch sent forwards at the same time?

All at the same time. To do so, it relies on batch processing, broadcasting, element-wise vectorization for non-linear operations (basically, a highly optimized for-loop, sometimes in parrallel) and matrix linear algebra. The later is much more efficient than a for-loop, since it can leverage dedicated hardware component designed for parallel linear algebra (this is true for both cpu and gpu, but gpu are especially well suited for this).

> Each instantiation could then be used to store the activations for one example in the minibatch. And therefore, multiple examples could be sent through the network simultaneously. However, I'm unsure whether this is actually done in practice.

This is not how it works, torch is keeping track of "operations", each of them having a `backward` used computing the gradient of the inputs wrt to the outputs. It is designed to support batch processing and vectorization, such that processing a bunch of samples is done at once as in single `backward` pass.

> I have done some simple experiments, and the time for a forward pass is roughly proportional to the minibatch size.

This is not true. It may be because you are already eating up 100% of the available resources (cpu or gpu), or because you are not doing the profiling properly (which is not so easy to do). If you post an example, one you try to help you on this point.